# Unable to click a link on a website using Selenium and Java

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, partiallinktext

I wish to click on the "Requests" link in the left panel of the website using selenium Java.

See the snapshot below where the xpathfinder shows element as:

```
/html/body/div[1]/nav/div/section/ul[3]/li/a/span[1]
```

[image]

Below is the part of my java code generated by selenium chrome browser IDE.

```
System.out.println("Title of the page is 7 -> Login");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='tv_3']/a/i")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Security Test Requests")).click();
driver.findElement(By.id("w0")).click();
```

Below is the view source of the page with the relevant part of the code having the Requests link.

```
</ul>
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
<li class="treeview" id='tv_3'>
<a href="#">
<i class="fa fa-edit"></i> <span>Requests</span>
<span class="pull-right-container" onclick="menu_dropdown('tv_3');"><i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i></span>
</a>
<ul class="treeview-menu">
<li><a href="/synvm/basic/web/index.php?r=request%2Findex-test-request"> Security Test Requests</a></li>
<li><a href="/synvm/basic/web/index.php?r=request%2Findex"> Exception Requests</a></li>
<li><a href="/synvm/basic/web/index.php?r=request%2Findex-change-request"> Change Requests</a></li>
<li><a href="/synvm/basic/web/index.php?r=request%2Findex-decommission-request"> Decommission Requests</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Edit: Uploaded the entire `View Source` of the webpage here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ov4Es3oDC66coaJADw6N1kxTorLmd3M6/view?usp=sharing

The issue is not with the page loading and wait of page. Infact the page gets loaded but the click on "Requests" shows a drop down which is not happening(The click)

I get the below error running my JAVA:

```
Title of the page is 7 -> Login
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Security Test Requests"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'VMINITSERMAPRAP', ip: '10.9.40.115', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\axmwiis\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:64908}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 3ca2879b253b55a953c0a481ec70ea78
*** Element info: {Using=link text, value=Security Test Requests}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

With the suggestion on this post I tried the below:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='sidebar-menu']/li[@class='treeview']/a//span[text()='Requests']"))).click();
```

But, I get the following error:

```
Title of the page is 7 -> Login
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //ul[@class='sidebar-memu']/li[@class='treeview']/a//span[text()='Requests'] (tried for 40 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:272)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.testSynvmRequest(SynvmRequest.java:135)
        at pack.SynvmRequest.main(SynvmRequest.java:398)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul[@class='sidebar-memu']/li[@class='treeview']/a//span[text()='Requests']"}
  (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.0', revision: '2ecb7d9a', time: '2018-10-31T20:09:30'
System info: host: 'MyHost', ip: '10.9.140.15', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 75.0.3770.100, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 75.0.3770.140 (2d9f97485c7b..., userDataDir: C:\Usersxmwiis\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:53969}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: XP, platformName: XP, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 979b2c191659cbbba7c43ebe4db9b5b9
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//ul[@class='sidebar-memu']/li[@class='treeview']/a//span[text()='Requests']}
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Can you please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

There is a space, and that's why selenium can not detect your element by linktext("Security Test Requests")

```
<li><a href="/synvm/basic/web/index.php?r=request%2Findex-test-request"> Security Test Requests</a></li>
```

your element should be

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText(" Security Test Requests")).click();
```

or you can use contains the method for XPath

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(), 'Security Test Requests')]").click();
```

Comment: Thank you @Norayr Sargsyan however, before clicking `  Security Test Requests` the challenge is to get the click working on `Requests`. I have uploaded the entire webpage code here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ov4Es3oDC66coaJADw6N1kxTorLmd3M6/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things as follows:

- The `<a>` element with text as **Requests** have a `onclick` event, so it's a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element.
- The `<a>` nodes with texts *Security Test Requests*, *Exception Requests*, *Change Requests* and *Decommission Requests* all of them have a leading white-space character. So `linkText` won't work.

---

### Solution

To click on the element with text as **Requests** and then on the element with text as **Security Test Requests** you need to use [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `partialLinkText`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//li[@id='tv_3']/a/i"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Security Test Requests"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='sidebar-menu']/li[@class='treeview']/a//span[text()='Requests']"))).click();
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//ul[@class='treeview-menu']//li/a[contains(., 'Security Test Requests')]"))).click();
  ```

Comment: I get an error trying your solution for `Requests` which I have updated now in my original post. Can you please suggest?

Comment: @Ashar Check if the _Request_ element is withinan `<iframe>`

Comment: I'm not very sure of iframes @DebanjanB so I uploaded the entire webpage view source code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ov4Es3oDC66coaJADw6N1kxTorLmd3M6/view?usp=sharing . Can you please suggest ?